# How to find values of the given $4n^2 - 5n + 16$ for which the function is a perfect square?

Tags: contest-math, square-numbers

**Problem:** Given a positive integer $m$, which can be written as $m^2 = 4n^2 - 5n + 16$, where $n$ is an integer of any sign, find the maximum value of $|m - n|$.

For this, I assumed $|m - n| = k$ then
$$k^2 = m^2 + n^2 - 2mn = 5n^2 - 5n + 16 - 2n\sqrt{4n^2 - 5n + 16}$$

Taking derivative to find increasing or decreasing intervals, keeping in mind that $4n^2 - 5n + 16$ must be a perfect square. I used wolfram to obtain values of $n$ for which the given expression was a perfect square, and it returned $n = 15,-15$ as the largest and smallest solutions, along with other solutions, and noting that the derivative is positive at $n=15$, this must be the point of maxima of $k$, thus $4(15)^2 - 5(15) + 16 =29^2$, which yields

$$k=|29-15| = 14$$

which is indeed the given answer.

My question is, how do I find values of $n$ for which $4n^2 - 5n + 16$ is a perfect square? I tried taking the expression modulo 4 and making cases to obtain something but didn't get anywhere. The problem is from IOQM 2023.

Completely different solutions to the problem are also welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Complete the square on the right hand side to get $m^2=(2n-5/4)^2+231/16$, or clearing denominators:

$$(4m)^2=(8n-5)^2+231$$

You can then write $231$ as the difference of two squares, and find all integer values of $m$ and $n$ which satisfy the diophantine equation.